# Getting keeks videos id from the link using php

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get just the Video Id from any keeks video link

Examples of Links from keeks.com

```
https://www.keek.com/syahrin/keeks/QC06cab
https://www.keek.com/!QC06cab
https://www.keek.com/syahrin#QC06cab
https://www.keek.com/embed/QC06cab
```

I need the output just `QC06cab`

Comment: Use regex. You want to get the string at the end that is preceded by {/, !, #} assuming that you have accounted for all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a character class that exclude delimiters and anchor the pattern to the end of the string:

```
if (preg_match('~[^/!#]++$~', $url, $match))
    print_r($match);
```

Comment: Thank You, But sorry I'm newbie to php and I need to know why the output is array and not just the id?

Comment: @Jim: because preg_match return always an array in the match value (see the doc). you can have the id with `$match[0]`